# Trying to get name instead of ID number SQL

Tags: sql

I have created a join for trying to get the manager last name instead the ID of the manager.

Here is the code I am using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    E.EmployeeID, E.LastName, E.FirstName, E.TitleOfCourtesy, m.ReportsTo AS 'Manager' 
FROM 
    Employees AS E
LEFT JOIN 
    Employees AS m ON E.ReportsTo = m.ReportsTo
```

But it still shows the ID of the manager and not the last name of the manager.

[image: Values]

For example: In the first row the manager is `EmployeeID 2` but instead the number 2 I want to have the last name `Fuller` of the `EmployeeID 2`

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN Employees AS m ON E.ReportsTo = m.EmployeeID`

Comment: @juergend When i do that, all the managers get `Null`

Comment: I doubt that. See my complete query.

Answer (score 0):

Join the other way, i.e. for each e, left join m to get the manager:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.EmployeeID, E.LastName, E.FirstName, E.TitleOfCourtesy,
                m.LastName, m.FirstName 
FROM Employees AS E
LEFT JOIN Employees AS m ON E.ReportsTo = m.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your join is incorrect. Use

```
 SELECT E.EmployeeID, E.LastName, E.FirstName, E.TitleOfCourtesy, 
        m.ReportsTo AS ManagerId, m.LastName AS ManagerName 
 FROM Employees AS E
 LEFT JOIN Employees AS m ON E.ReportsTo = m.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! But now there still is the Column `ManagerID` with `null` can i remove that column from the query?

Comment: Please be more specific what you mean or ask a new question